# Effect of Regularization on bias and variance

Tags: lasso, regularization, tikhonov-regularization

I have already seen several related questions: [1](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/141555/how-does-regularization-reduce-overfitting), [2](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/64208/why-do-overfitted-models-tend-to-have-large-coefficients/64235#64235), [3](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/179864/why-does-shrinkage-work), [4](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/300438/relationship-between-bias-variance-and-regularization), [5](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/328261/how-do-machine-learning-methods-employ-regularization-to-reduce-variance).

The answer to [1](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/141555/how-does-regularization-reduce-overfitting) states

> Regularization attemts to reduce the variance of the estimator by simplifying it, something that will increase the bias, in such a way that the expected error decreases.

How do we show, mathematically, that regularization (say $L_2$ or others) increases bias and decreases variance? None of the answers to the linked questions seem to "prove" this.

I am aware of the Bias-Variance tradeoff:
$$\mathbb{E}\big[(\hat{\theta}-\theta)^2\big] = \mathbb{E}\big[\hat{\theta}-\theta\big]^2 + \mathbb{E}\big[(\hat{\theta}-\mathbb{E}(\hat{\theta}))^2\big]$$

Comment: good question, of course this won't be true for all $\theta$; we need to make some assumptions about it. You may be interested in this reading: https://efron.ckirby.su.domains//other/CASI_Chap7_Nov2014.pdf